# Why is my C code not keeping the state of static variables?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

So, all information I've found online points to JNI keeping state of global variables defined on C.

However, In my particular case, this isn't working.

C Code:

```
//*snip* (just the includes) 
static int sockfd = -2;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {

    printf("Calling onLoad\n");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}


JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL cinit
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){

  sockfd = 5; //This would normally be the socket initialization code, but this is a lot simpler and also fails. 

  printf("Open %d\n",sockdf); // This prints 5. 

  return 1; 

}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL cwrite
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jbyteArray bytes){
    // a is a valid array.
    printf("Write %d\n",sockfd); // This prints -2!!!! 
    if ((b = write(sockfd, a, sizeof(a))) < 0){
        perror("write"); 
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The Java code just inits the library with a single loadLibrary inside a static block, and then calls open, then write in sucession.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

The prints I get from those are:

Calling onLoad
Open 5
Write -2

EDIT: simplified the example a bit more, and added the suggestions from the comments.

Comment: Show the `//*snip*. Esentially some code to initialize socket`

Comment: Check whether the `.so` is loaded only once using `JNI_OnLoad` ?

Comment: If all of what you're saying is true, this is not possible. But `init` is not `open`. You don't post the socket initialization. You say you're doing printf's but the calls are not shown. You don't actually say what the output of the perror line is. But regardless, no code would set sockfd back to -1, other than e.g. `open` or the C library initialisation. You could test for this by setting it to e.g. -2 initially. Certainly no normal syscall would set that, so then you know whether it's a syscall or reinitialization that causes this. That should never happen if the lib is loaded only once.

Comment: Within `JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL write` you are calling `write` (the syscall). Do the names conflict? Can you rename your JNI function?